# How to update UI in Header component based on the footer visibility in Knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a Header component and footer component as custom elements in Knockout js. When i have integrated these two components in a page. When the page is in mobile view i need to show action buttons of the header at the bottom . But this bottom buttons has different bottom values because footer visibility is optional.Header Action buttons bottom value will change based on the footer visibility.  What is the best approach to do this in Knockout js.

Comment: You could make completely separate components for mobile and desktop views (or components with separate sections), and switch their visibility based on CSS media queries. This way Knockout would not need to become involved at all.

Comment: @Tomalak Actually it is completely different view for mobile and desktop. The problem here is header has button with bottom 0 (in the mobile view )when there is no footer . If footer is there then buttons of header should have bottom of 32px. So i am sending an event from footer if header needs to have 32px bottom. but its firing after header is loaded then adding 32px creating flickering issue.

Comment: Then please show a [mcve] (runnable code) that contains a minimal viewmodel, minimal data, and that demonstrates the issue.